# Insert values of arraylist into mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to insert values from arraylist into mysql table.

```
List lstUnique=new ArrayList<Object>();
//code to feed the data into list from resultset.
try{          
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYdb","root","");
    stmt=con.createStatement();
    String sql1="select SourceFrom,Updated,Location_Type,Industry,ET_Rank,BT_Rank from mytable";
    rs1=stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
    rsmd=rs1.getMetaData();
    columnNumber=rsmd.getColumnCount();

    while(rs1.next()){
       lstUnique.add(rs1.getString("SourceFrom")+","+rs1.getString("Updated")+","+rs1.getString("Location_Type")+","+
                 rs1.getString("Industry")+","+rs1.getString("ET_Rank")+","+rs1.getString("BT_Rank")); 
    }
    String insertsql="";
    String SourceFrom=lstUnique.get(0).toString(); //its first column of the table.
    insertsql="Insert into java_uniquedata (SourceFrom,field2,field3,field4,field5) values(?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(insertsql);

    //I tried this way also.
    for(int i=0;i<lstUnique.size();i++){
        SourceFrom=lstUnique.get(i).toString();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<lstUnique.size();i++){
        System.out.println("\n" + lstUnique.get(i).toString());
    }
    rs1.close();
    con.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

But I am getting error

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

My list has only one record in it, which has total 5 columns' values. Can you guide me how do I fetch values of first record from arraylist and insert it into mysql table.

Comment: show us *"code to feed the data into list from resultset"*

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I have edited.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko how do I store all fields value from arraylist and then insert the same in various columns of mytable in mysql?

Comment: it seems you didn't fetch anything from the db, can you put a `sout` call inside the `while(rs1.next())` and provide a result?

Comment: No its correct. I have fetched and put sout also to verify whether it has first  record in it or not. and it showed that.

Comment: @iks_in please try to provide code in a way, that has at least a chance to compile. Currently there's an partial `try` block without closing bracket and  `catch`. // Also according to Java Coding Conventions, variable names should start with a lower case letter, your `SourceFrom` does not. //  And please provide the full Stacktrace.

Comment: What happens to `SourceFrom` anyway?

Comment: are you getting exception inside for loop?

Comment: @JekinKalariya yes

Comment: just debug , how namy times your for loop execute..If you dont know to debug try to remove your current code and  print sysout

Comment: Its now execute it once. then go to catch block and print the exception.

Answer (score 2):

You should separate the values for your insert statement. Either use a custom datastructure (class) or use a `List<String>`.

Something like this might work:

```
List<List<String>> lstUnique=new ArrayList<>();  // note the List of List    
try {          
    /* ... your database query here ... */

    while(rs1.next()){
       List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(); // create list for values
       values.add(rs1.getString("SourceFrom"));
       values.add(rs1.getString("Updated"));
       values.add(rs1.getString("Location_Type"));
       values.add(rs1.getString("Industry"));
       values.add(rs1.getString("ET_Rank"));
       values.add(rs1.getString("BT_Rank"));
       lstUnique.add(values);  // add values for each row
    }

    String insertsql="Insert into java_uniquedata (SourceFrom,field2,field3,field4,field5) values(?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(insertsql);
    for(List<String> values : lstUnique) { // use for each for rows
        for(int i=0;i<values.size();i++) { // set argument values to prepared statement
            ps.setString((i+1), values.get(i));
        }
        ps.execute(); // execute insert statement
    }
    ps.close();
} catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
} finally {  // close recordset and connection in finally-block! (or use 'try-with-resource'!)
    rs1.close();
    con.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am trying on it. Will let you know if I find any difficulties.

Comment: I am getting an error in inner for loop,  `'for(List<String> values ; lstUnique.size() ) { // use for each for rows
        for(int i=0;i<values.size();i++)` What do I do?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Edited the answer.

Comment: Oh my bad too. Did not notice such simple thing. Thanks a lot.. Trying again.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it inserts data into database

```
ArrayList<String> lis = new ArrayList<String>();
lis.add("pare1");
lis.add("2");

//code to feed the data into list from resultset.
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "paresh");
String insertsql="";
insertsql="Insert into stud (name,age) VALUES (?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement(insertsql);
```

//this will set value for your insert statement

```
System.out.println(lis.get(0).toString());
ps.setString(1, lis.get(0).toString());
ps.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(lis.get(1)));
System.out.println(ps);
ps.execute(insertsql);
```

Comment: Question was updated. `lstUnique` does not contain the single values, but a concatenated string. That might be one of the problems.

Comment: @paresh, I've tried this way also but it still gave me the same error.

Comment: @MarkusMitterauer, yes I felt the same. Then what is the way to fetch data from arraylist and insert into mysql table?

Comment: @iks_in See my [new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39269837/4791599).

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
for(int i=0; i < lstUnique.size();i++){
     ps.setString(1, lstUnique.get(i).toString());
}
ps.execute(insertsql);
```

Comment: But do I need to change in my insert query? Its having ? in values (?,?) field.

Comment: I've tried this way but now its giving me an error for com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,' at line 1

Comment: i dont know unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Completely different aproach for a solution to the task, if it is not mandatory to be solved in Java(?):

Since your code sample gives the impression that you're reading from and writing to the same database, you might also consider to copy the data in-database using the SQL `INSERT-SELECT` Syntax:

```
INSERT INTO java_uniquedata (SourceFrom, field2, field3, field4, field5) 
    SELECT DISTINCT SourceFrom, Updated, Location_Type, Industry, ET_Rank, BT_Rank 
    FROM mytable;
```

See [MySQL INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. +1 for that. I am aware of this. But I am doing it in java because I actually want to find unique records from my huge database. So I take the data into resultset then add it in a list, through list, I will insert first row into the table, then I will compare each row with the existing rows of table whether they are duplicates, if yes then I will not insert such record, if its partially duplicate then I will update the existing record of my table else I will insert the row.

Comment: You're welcome. If it's just about the data, you can ensure uniqueness with SQL too, using the `DISTINCT` keyword. Updated my answer. // btw. you can do that too with your Java solution.

Comment: I've tried distinct too, but I've very very bad data. So the problem is, if field1,field2,f3 are there in one row while firld1,field4,field5 in another row, it didnt give me unique record. And there are actually 45 columns in that database. Its too messy. They way data is stored, its difficult to find unique records using SQL.

Comment: Ah.  Okay. Couldn't see that from the code in your questions. That would probably make it difficult with SQL.

Comment: Yeah. That's a big challenge for me now.

Comment: I am trying to solve it since last two weeks but still no success.